# Why is my Intel NUC dying when watching H265?

Tags: debian, logs, hardware, video

I've been using my BOXD34010WYKH1 Intel NUC for over 5 years now as my media center. It's been attached to my TV, running LibreElec (Kodi). I've watched many h264 1080p videos on it, streamed over the network from my NAS, with no issues.

Recently, I've tried some 1080p HEVC 10bit content, and my NUC can't handle it. I can't figure out why. It'll run the h265 video perfectly smooth for several minutes. Plenty of free RAM left. CPU is only about 70% on all 4 cores. lm_sensors shows temperatures of about 50 degrees C. Then, all of a sudden, the screen goes dark, and freezes.

I thought maybe it was a software issues, so I tried updating LibreElec - didn't help. I then tried installing Linux Mint, setting up a Plex server on another machine, and watching through firefox on the NUC. Exactly the same thing - runs fine for a few minutes, and then it dies.

The only clue I have is this:

When running Linux Mint, I'm sshed into the NUC from my laptop, following logs as I watch the videos until it dies. When it dies, I get these log entries in /var/log/syslog:

```
May 12 19:50:26 tal-media-nuc kernel: [  228.055952] nuvoton-cir 00:05: RX FIFO overrun detected, flushing data!                                                      [6/23]
May 12 19:50:26 tal-media-nuc kernel: [  228.058145] nuvoton-cir 00:05: RX FIFO overrun detected, flushing data!
May 12 19:50:26 tal-media-nuc kernel: [  228.059121] nuvoton-cir 00:05: RX FIFO overrun detected, flushing data!
May 12 19:50:26 tal-media-nuc kernel: [  228.060019] nuvoton-cir 00:05: RX FIFO overrun detected, flushing data!
May 12 19:50:26 tal-media-nuc kernel: [  228.062556] nuvoton-cir 00:05: RX FIFO overrun detected, flushing data!
May 12 19:50:26 tal-media-nuc kernel: [  228.062836] nuvoton-cir 00:05: RX FIFO overrun detected, flushing data!
May 12 19:50:29 tal-media-nuc kernel: [  231.751820] ata1.00: exception Emask 0x10 SAct 0x3f8000 SErr 0x4040000 action 0xe frozen
May 12 19:50:29 tal-media-nuc kernel: [  231.751832] ata1.00: irq_stat 0x00000040, connection status changed
May 12 19:50:29 tal-media-nuc kernel: [  231.751837] ata1: SError: { CommWake DevExch }
May 12 19:50:29 tal-media-nuc kernel: [  231.751843] ata1.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
May 12 19:50:29 tal-media-nuc kernel: [  231.751849] ata1.00: cmd 61/18:78:d8:7a:d4/00:00:1f:00:00/40 tag 15 ncq dma 12288 out
May 12 19:50:29 tal-media-nuc kernel: [  231.751849]          res 50/00:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
May 12 19:50:29 tal-media-nuc kernel: [  231.751851] ata1.00: status: { DRDY }
May 12 19:50:29 tal-media-nuc kernel: [  231.751853] ata1.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
May 12 19:50:29 tal-media-nuc kernel: [  231.751857] ata1.00: cmd 61/68:80:48:94:d4/01:00:1f:00:00/40 tag 16 ncq dma 184320 out
May 12 19:50:29 tal-media-nuc kernel: [  231.751857]          res 50/00:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
May 12 19:50:29 tal-media-nuc kernel: [  231.751860] ata1.00: status: { DRDY }
May 12 19:50:29 tal-media-nuc kernel: [  231.751863] ata1.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
May 12 19:50:29 tal-media-nuc kernel: [  231.751867] ata1.00: cmd 61/f0:88:18:cd:f1/07:00:1f:00:00/40 tag 17 ncq dma 1040384 ou
May 12 19:50:29 tal-media-nuc kernel: [  231.751867]          res 50/00:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
May 12 19:50:29 tal-media-nuc kernel: [  231.751868] ata1.00: status: { DRDY }
May 12 19:50:29 tal-media-nuc kernel: [  231.751870] ata1.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
May 12 19:50:29 tal-media-nuc kernel: [  231.751874] ata1.00: cmd 61/10:90:08:d5:f1/08:00:1f:00:00/40 tag 18 ncq dma 1056768 ou
May 12 19:50:29 tal-media-nuc kernel: [  231.751874]          res 50/00:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
May 12 19:50:29 tal-media-nuc kernel: [  231.751876] ata1.00: status: { DRDY }
May 12 19:50:29 tal-media-nuc kernel: [  231.751877] ata1.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
May 12 19:50:29 tal-media-nuc kernel: [  231.751881] ata1.00: cmd 61/00:98:18:dd:f1/0a:00:1f:00:00/40 tag 19 ncq dma 1310720 ou
May 12 19:50:29 tal-media-nuc kernel: [  231.751881]          res 50/00:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
May 12 19:50:29 tal-media-nuc kernel: [  231.751883] ata1.00: status: { DRDY }
May 12 19:50:29 tal-media-nuc kernel: [  231.751884] ata1.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
May 12 19:50:29 tal-media-nuc kernel: [  231.751888] ata1.00: cmd 61/00:a0:18:e7:f1/06:00:1f:00:00/40 tag 20 ncq dma 786432 out
May 12 19:50:29 tal-media-nuc kernel: [  231.751888]          res 50/00:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
May 12 19:50:29 tal-media-nuc kernel: [  231.751890] ata1.00: status: { DRDY }
May 12 19:50:29 tal-media-nuc kernel: [  231.751892] ata1.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
May 12 19:50:29 tal-media-nuc kernel: [  231.751896] ata1.00: cmd 61/b8:a8:18:ed:f1/08:00:1f:00:00/40 tag 21 ncq dma 1142784 ou
May 12 19:50:29 tal-media-nuc kernel: [  231.751896]          res 50/00:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
May 12 19:50:29 tal-media-nuc kernel: [  231.751897] ata1.00: status: { DRDY }
May 12 19:50:29 tal-media-nuc kernel: [  231.751909] ata1: hard resetting link
May 12 19:50:32 tal-media-nuc kernel: [  234.239049] ata1: SATA link down (SStatus 1 SControl 300)
May 12 19:50:32 tal-media-nuc kernel: [  234.239364] ata1: hard resetting link
May 12 19:50:34 tal-media-nuc kernel: [  236.466987] ata1: COMRESET failed (errno=-32)
May 12 19:50:34 tal-media-nuc kernel: [  236.466995] ata1: reset failed (errno=-32), retrying in 8 secs
May 12 19:50:42 tal-media-nuc kernel: [  244.253793] ata1: hard resetting link
May 12 19:50:44 tal-media-nuc kernel: [  246.465503] ata1: SATA link down (SStatus 1 SControl 300)
May 12 19:50:44 tal-media-nuc kernel: [  246.466243] ata1: hard resetting link
```

SSH stays connected, but my bash goes crazy. If I run `ls`, or any other command, it says `ls: command not found`. If I run something like `/usr/bin/ls`, it says `-bash: /usr/bin/ls: Input/output error`. If I disconnect SSH, and try to reconnect, it won't let me. I have to hard reset the NUC to get back into it.

I took out the 2.5" drive from the NUC, and had it examined. SMART says it's fine. badblocks says it's fine.

This only happens with HEVC. H264 still plays without any issues. I don't know if it's some sort of hardware bug, or some hardware is failing, or if there's anything I can do about it. If I knew this was just a matter of needing a more powerful NUC, I'd go buy one, but it seems like it's not even close to maxing out its resources when playing the videos. I have no guarantee the new one won't do the same thing.

Comment: Your cpu is one generation too early to have gotten built in dedicated hevc decoding hardware. You can obviously play the video via software decoding but as your seeing, it can't keep up. Pretty much every graphics chip from ARM, Intel, Nvidia, and AMD after 2015 and on started adding built in h265 hardware decoders. Have you confirmed that all the firmware and drivers are installed for your device? Are you on the latest BIOS too?

Comment: That's the thing - as far as I can tell, it CAN keep up. It doesn't lag, the CPU isn't maxed out, the RAM isn't maxed out. It plays perfectly smooth for the first few minutes. I have not updated my BIOS - I suppose I could try that. I'm not sure which firmware and drivers you are talking about. The CPU doesn't generally require drivers as far as I know. The GPU is not AMD or NVIDIA, so I wouldn't think it would require any kind of proprietary drivers either.

Comment: You have an Intel graphics chip. Have you installed all the drivers for it is what I am asking. Intel is probably the best when it comes to open sourcing their drivers but there might be better software decoders available to you. Additionally, you might need to install something to monitor when you crash so you can get a better idea of what is going wrong. I can't recommend one as I don't know what is specifically crashing so I don't know what tool you will need.

Comment: Not sure where I would even look for Intel drivers. Like you said, Intel is really good at open-sourcing their drivers, so as far as I know, they are just built into the kernel. Also, if I knew what was crashing, I wouldn't be here trying to get help figuring out what's crashing.